# Scale coloring of ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

The answer given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64330/set-the-same-color-scale-across-multiple-listcontourplots) solved how to use the same color scale across multiple plots within the function ListContourPlot. I can't for the life of me map this solution onto the function ContourPlot that I am using.

Say for example I have the code

```
r = Norm[{x, y}];
plot1 = Plot3D[{r^2, -r^2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 3}];
plot2 = ContourPlot[r^2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"];
GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2}]
```

which gives me the plots. If you look at the code you will see that in the contour plot I am only plotting the positive solutions and so for consistency my plot should be contours that are shades of red.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

*****EDIT 1*****

kguler submitted an answer that solved this example question, but for a reason I can't understand it doesn't work in the actual system that I'm using. Here is my full code:

```
    Clear["Global`*"];
DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> Infinity;

(*Nearest neighbour vectors*)
{e1, e2, 
   e3} = # & /@ {{0, -1}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {-Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}};

(*dispersion*)
w[theta_, phi_] := Module[{c1, c2, c3, fq},
  {c1, c2, c3} = 
   1 - 3 Sin[theta]^2 Cos[phi - 2 Pi (# - 1)/3]^2 & /@ {1, 2, 3};
  fq = Total[#[[1]] Exp[I q.#[[2]]] & /@ {{c1, e1}, {c2, e2}, {c3, 
       e3}}];
  Sqrt[1 + 2 # Omega Norm[fq]] & /@ {1, -1}
  ]



Omega = 0.01; 
q = {qx, qy};



(***Figure3a***)
{theta, phi} = {Pi/2, Pi/2};
dirac3a = {(2/Sqrt[3]) ArcCos[2/5], 4 Pi/3};
zoom = 0.005 Pi;

With[
 {plotopts = {Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7], 
    Ticks -> {{1.33, 1.34, 1.35}, {4.18, 4.19, 4.20}, Automatic}, 
    BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
    AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
    ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", LabelStyle -> Large, 
    ClippingStyle -> None, BoxStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
    ViewPoint -> {1.43, -2.84, 1.13}, ViewVertical -> {0., 0., 1.}}},
 figure3a = Plot3D[w[theta, phi],
   {qx, dirac3a[[1]] - zoom, dirac3a[[1]] + zoom}, {qy, 
    dirac3a[[2]] - zoom, dirac3a[[2]] + zoom}, plotopts]
 ]


(***Figure3b***)
With[{plotopts = {Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{{4.18, 4.19, 4.20}, None}, {{1.33, 1.34, 1.35}, 
       None}}, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
    LabelStyle -> Large, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {0.9996, 1.0004}}]
    }
  },
 figure3b = ContourPlot[w[theta, phi][[1]],
   {qx, dirac3a[[1]] - zoom, dirac3a[[1]] + zoom}, {qy, 
    dirac3a[[2]] - zoom, dirac3a[[2]] + zoom}, plotopts]
 ]

(***Figure3b legend***)

legend = {0.9996 + 0.0001 #, 0.9996 + 0.0001 #} & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8};
figure3bLegend = 
 ArrayPlot[legend, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
  DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.9996, 1.0004}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{0.9996, 0.9997, 0.9998, 0.9999, {1.0000, "1.0000"}, 
     1.0001, 1.0002, 1.0003, 1.0004}, None}, AspectRatio -> 7, 
  LabelStyle -> Large]
```

where I have incorporated the suggestion, but it gives me a plot that is monochrome. The values 0.9996 and 1.0004 correspond to the maxima and minima.

[image]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
plot1 = Plot3D[{r^2, -r^2}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {-20, 20}}], 
   BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 3}];
plot2 = ContourPlot[r^2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {-20, 20}}]];

Legended[GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2}], BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {-20, 20}}, 20]]
```

[image]

**Update:** For the specific example in OP's updated question, the following changes produce the desired result:

Change `plotops` appearing in the part generating `figure3b` to

```
plotopts = {Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{4.18, 4.19, 4.20}, None}, {{1.33, 1.34, 1.35}, 
     None}}, LabelStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {0.9996, 1.0004}}]}
```

and use the same scaled colors in the `ArrayPlot` that generates the legend:

```
figure3bLegend = 
 ArrayPlot[legend, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ImageSize -> {200, 350}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {0.9996, 1.0004}}],
   DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.9996, 1.0004}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{0.9996, 0.9997, 0.9998, 0.9999, {1.0000, "1.0000"}, 
     1.0001, 1.0002, 1.0003, 1.0004}, None}, AspectRatio -> 7, 
  LabelStyle -> Large]
```

and add the option `ImageSize->400` in `plotops` used in generation of `figure3a`.

With these changes

```
Row[{figure3a, figure3b, figure3bLegend}, Spacer[5]]
```

gives
[image]

Comment: I'm actually having a little trouble. I edited my question to reflect this

Comment: Tom, could you include in your post the values/definitions of `w, theta, phi, dirac3a, zoom` so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry yes that's more helpful, question updated.

Comment: Tom, you have `ColorFunction` appearing twice in your `plotopts` and the second one is ignored. If you remove the first one, i.e., `plotopts = {Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{{4.18, 4.19, 4.20}, None}, {{1.33, 1.34, 1.35},  None}}, LabelStyle -> Large, PlotRangePadding -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", {0.9996, 1.0004}}]}`, it should work.