# Fixed colors for fixed values in contourplot legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to make a contour plot of a gravitational potential, consisting of a sum og different potential.s.

I would like to plot them separately with a BarLegend that has the same colors for the same values of the potential. What I got now is that the colors in the two plots does not represent the same potential energy. Here's an example:

```
contplotb = 
  ContourPlot[1/Sqrt[R^2 + z^2 + 1], {R, 0, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All, LegendFunction -> "Panel"]]

 contplotd = 
  ContourPlot[3/Sqrt[R^2 + z^2 + 1], {R, 0, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All, LegendFunction -> "Panel"]]
```

[image]

As you may see, the colors represent different values, but it would be nice to have them represent the same

Any tips are much apreciated, and please include code if you have a solution, I'm very new to Mathematica.

Thanks
Espen

Comment: closely related Q/As:  [Scale coloring of ContourPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64366/125) and [Set the same color scale across multiple ListContourPlots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64330/125)

Comment: Use `ColorFunction -> 
 ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 3}}], ColorFunctionScaling -> False` on both plots

Comment: Thank you, guys! I checked out those other posts, but they seemed a bit more advanced than what I was after. Belisarius' answer worked just as I was hoping for.

Comment: @belisarius Answer, or Close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Belisarius answered this in comments, this is just so people know that it has been dealt with.

Use

```
ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 3}}], ColorFunctionScaling -> False
```

for each plot.