# How can I create an interactive ColorFunction using Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, color

I am trying to specify my own colors and scaling for the [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) in [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html). I have several lists of 2D values which I plot in multiple images, and I want to scale the data according to the absolute maximum and minimum value taken from all the lists.

I want to visualize all the data, but some lists contain quite small values, and a few lists contain data approximately 100× larger.

I have been trying to use [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html), with the intention of scaling from the minimum to the maximum of the plotted values, using custom colors:

```
MyPlot = ListDensityPlot[Transpose[Join[Transpose[Points],
                                        Rescale[Transpose[#], {MinV, MaxV}]]],
                         AspectRatio -> Automatic,
                         ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, Purple}, {0.5, Blue},
                                                  {1, Green}, {3, Yellow},
                                                  {6, Red}}, #] &),
                         ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
                         PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
                         PlotRange -> All] &;
```

However, I was thinking that it would be nice to create something like a [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) bar to change the values related to the used colors and "tune" the colors in a more comfortable way.

Can anyone give me advice on how to implement it?

Comment: Recent and related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64338/193

Comment: Check out RM's [ColorBar](https://github.com/rsmenon/ColorBar) which works a lot like MATLAB's version.

Answer (score 13):

This is a really neat idea, and I'm happy with how straightforward it was to make, and fun it is to move the sliders around:

```
Manipulate[
 {a, x, y, z, b} = 
  Rescale[{aa, xx, yy, zz, bb}, MinMax@{aa, xx, yy, zz, bb}];
 colors = 
  Transpose[{{a, x, y, z, b}, {Purple, Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}}];
 DensityPlot[
  Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -2 π, 2 π},
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[colors, #] &), PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 100],
 {{aa, 0, "Purple"}, 0, 1, .01},
 {{xx, .25, "Blue"}, 0, 1, .01},
 {{yy, .5, "Green"}, 0, 1, .01},
 {{zz, .75, "Yellow"}, 0, 1, .01},
 {{bb, 1, "Red"}, 0, 1, .01}]
Dynamic[colors]
```

[image]

After you've moved the slider and found the color function you like, the list of colors and their values are stored in the global variable `colors` and so you can recover the final `ColorFunction` as `(Blend[colors, #]&)`

### Total control over colors and Blend

You can easily use `Manipulate` to make a custom color function like this,

```
Manipulate[
  {a, x, y, z, b} = 
    Rescale[{aa, xx, yy, zz, bb}, MinMax@{ aa, xx, yy, zz, bb}];
  colors = 
    Transpose[{{a, x, y, z, b}, {color1, color2, color3, color4, 
     color5}}];
  DensityPlot[
    Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -2 π, 2 π},
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[colors, #] &), PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    PlotPoints -> 100],
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{aa, 0, ""}, 0, 1}], 
    Control[{{color1, Purple, "Color1"}, Red}]},
   {Control[{{xx, .25, ""}, 0, 1}], 
    Control[{{color2, Cyan, "Color2"}, Red}]},
   {Control[{{yy, .5, ""}, 0, 1}], 
    Control[{{color3, Brown, "Color3"}, Red}]},
   {Control[{{zz, .75, ""}, 0, 1}], 
    Control[{{color4, Yellow, "Color4"}, Red}]},
   {Control[{{bb, 1, ""}, 0, 1}], 
    Control[{{color5, Magenta, "Color5"}, Red}]}
   }],
 ControlPlacement -> Top
  ]
Dynamic[colors]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I recently needed to do something like this. The only wrinkle is that I did not find `Manipulate[]` to be sufficiently flexible for my needs, so I fell back on using `DynamicModule[]`. Hopefully, this is still admissible.

```
With[{cmax = 12}, (* maximum number of colors *)
     DynamicModule[{k = 3, cols = {Red, White, Blue}, vals = {0., 0.5, 1.}}, 
                   Panel[Column[{Column[{
                   Row[{Dynamic[Style["colors: " <> IntegerString[k], Bold]], Spacer[20], 
                        Slider[Dynamic[k, (k = #; cols = PadRight[cols, k, Gray]; 
                                           vals = Rescale[ArrayPad[vals,
                                                                   {0, k - Length[vals]},
                                                                   "Extrapolated"]]) &],
                               {2, cmax, 1}]}], 
                   Dynamic[Multicolumn[Array[
                   Column[{ColorSlider[Dynamic[cols[[#]]]], 
                           Row[{Dynamic[Style[vals[[#]], Small, Bold]], Spacer[20], 
                           Slider[Dynamic[vals[[#]]], ImageSize -> Small]}]}] &, k], 6,
                                  Appearance -> "Horizontal"], TrackedSymbols :> {k}]}], 
                   Dynamic[With[{cl = Transpose[{vals, cols}]}, 
                                Column[{Panel[LinearGradientImage[Blend[cl, #] &,
                                                                  {600, 60}]], 
                                        Button["Copy to clipboard", 
                                               CopyToClipboard[Defer[Blend[cl, #] &]],
                                               ImageSize -> Medium,
                                               Method -> "Queued"]}]]]}]]]]
```

[image: interactive color gradient maker]

(Thanks to Karsten for some suggested improvements.)

---

**update 9/10/2017**

Prompted by [this Wolfram Community post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/847480) by Kevin Daily, I've written an expanded version of the interface given above:

[image: extended interactive color gradient maker]

Apart from creating your own, one can now load the available color gradients into *Mathematica* for editing. I've added a "Resample" mode (versus the original "Pad" mode), which allows one to make a finer (or coarser, as the case may be) resampling of the currently loaded gradient. Finally, one can now use the sliders to the right of the `ColorSlider[]` objects to tweak the $\alpha$ parameter for a color.

Here is the interface being used to edit `"M10DefaultDensityGradient"`:

[image: editing a built-in color gradient]

The code is now quite a bit longer, but hopefully not very:

```
With[{cmax = 18},
     DynamicModule[{k = 3, cols = {Red, White, Blue}, vals = {0., 0.5, 1.},
                    alf = {1, 1, 1}, grad = None, mode = 2, tmp},
                   Deploy[Panel[Column[{Column[{Row[{
                          PopupMenu[Dynamic[grad,
                                            (grad = #;
                                             tmp = ColorData[grad, "BlendArgument"];
                                             k = Length[tmp]; 
                                             alf = ConstantArray[1, k]; 
                                             If[ArrayDepth[tmp] == 1, cols = tmp; 
                                                vals = N[Subdivide[k - 1]],
                                                {vals, cols} = Transpose[tmp]];) &], 
                                    Join[ColorData["Gradients"], {Delimiter}, 
                                         ColorData["ThemeGradients"]],
                                    "Select gradient…"],
                          Spacer[30],
                          Dynamic[Style["colors: " <> IntegerString[k], Bold]], 
                          Spacer[10], 
                          Slider[Dynamic[k, (k = #; alf = PadRight[alf, k, 1];
                                             If[mode == 1,
                                                cols = PadRight[cols, k, Gray]; 
                                                vals = 
                                                Rescale[ArrayPad[vals, {0,
                                                                 k - Length[vals]},
                                                                 "Extrapolated"]],
                                                tmp = N[Subdivide[k - 1]]; 
                                                cols =
                                                With[{cl = Transpose[{vals, cols}]}, 
                                                     Blend[cl, #] & /@ tmp];
                                                vals = tmp]) &], {2, cmax, 1}],
                          Spacer[30], Style["mode:", Bold], Spacer[5], 

                          RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[mode], {1 -> "Pad", 2 -> "Resample"},
                                         Appearance -> "Row"]}], 
                          Dynamic[Multicolumn[Array[
                                  Column[{Row[{ColorSlider[Dynamic[cols[[#]]]], 
                                               Spacer[5], 
                                               VerticalSlider[Dynamic[alf[[#]]],
                                                              ImageSize ->
                                                              {Automatic, 40}]}], 
                                          Row[{Dynamic[Style[vals[[#]], Small, Bold]],
                                          Spacer[20],
                                          Slider[Dynamic[vals[[#]]],
                                                 ImageSize -> Small]}]}] &,
                                  k], 6, Appearance -> "Horizontal"],
                                  TrackedSymbols :> {k}]}], 
                          Dynamic[With[{cl = Transpose[{vals, 
                                                        If[Max[Unitize[1 - alf]] == 0,
                                                           cols,
                                                           MapThread[Append,
                                                                     {cols, alf}]]}]}, 
                                       Column[{Panel[LinearGradientImage[Blend[cl, #] &,
                                                                         {600, 60}]],
                                               Button["Copy to clipboard", 
                                                      CopyToClipboard[Defer[InputForm[
                                                                      Blend[cl, #] &]]], 
                                                      ImageSize -> Medium,
                                                      Method -> "Queued"]}]]]}]]]]]
```

Comment: The `vals` `Slider` are unresponsive when I'm trying to move them while keeping the left mouse button clicked.  I can only change their values with single mouse clicks. Adding `TrackedSymbols :> {k}` to the `Dynamic` wrapped around `Multicolumn` solves that issue. But now the styled `vals` also need to be `Dynamic`, which makes the spacing change.

Comment: Yes, those tweaks certainly improved the response time. Thanks @Karsten! I will edit this in a few.