# How to recreate the gnuplot color scheme "AFM Hot" in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, color

I'm trying to build an 3D AFM image from raw data with *Mathematica*. So how do I recreate the "AFM hot" color scheme? I've tried `"SolarColors"` and `"RustTones"`, but they don't quite do the job.

"AFM hot" looks like this (I took this picture from [here](http://www.rcnp.osaka-u.ac.jp/~noji/colormap)):

Test function:

```
f[x_, y_] := 0.1 + (1 - (x - 2)^2) (1 - (y - 2)^2)
```

[image: AFM Hot]

Comment: Perhaps [THIS](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/142819) can help.

Comment: Related question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127306/colormaps-for-linear-visual-perception-and-grayscale-printing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So these gnuplot color maps are a little bit more complicated than can be easily achieved by `Blend` (although you can do some [cool stuff](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107573/9490) with `Blend`).

If you look at [this page](http://juluribk.com/2011/05/18/843/) you can see that they specify a particular mapping function for the three different RGB components as a function of the scaling parameter `x`.

AFMHot uses functions 33, 34, and 35, which correspond to `2 x`, `2 x - 0.5`, and `2x - 1.0`, where `x` goes from 0 to 1

```
afmHot = RGBColor[2 #, 2 # - .5, 2 # - 1] &;

Plot3D[0.1 + (1 - (x - 2)^2) (1 - (y - 2)^2), {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, afmHot[z]] ]
DensityPlot[
 0.1 + (1 - (x - 2)^2) (1 - (y - 2)^2), {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3},
 ColorFunction -> afmHot , PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You can do the rest of the color maps via

```
traditional = RGBColor[Sqrt[#], #^3, Sin[2 π #]] &;
greenRedViolet = RGBColor[#, Abs[# - .5], #^4] &;
ocean = RGBColor[3 # - 2, Abs[(3 # - 1)/2], #] &;
hot = RGBColor[3 #, 3 # - 1, 3 # - 2] &;
rainbow = RGBColor[Abs[2 # - .5], Sin[π #], Cos[π/2 #]] &;
afmHot = RGBColor[2 #, 2 # - .5, 2 # - 1] &;

LinearGradientImage[#, {300, 100}] & /@ {traditional, greenRedViolet, 
   ocean, hot, rainbow, afmHot} // Column
```

[image]

Comment: The component functions are (piecewise) linear, so `Blend[]` can be used here. See my answer.

Comment: Right on - but could you do the nonlinear ones, the ones that call on `Sqrt` and trig functions?  Also, what is meant by the notation in component 32?

Comment: Of course, you can't use `Blend[]` on those colors. ;) I'm not sure about those semicolons, I've looked through the manual and all I can find was that they're just separators.

Comment: Okay, it's apparently a piecewise function. Try this: `f303132[x_] := RGBColor[Clip[25 x/8 - 25/32 , {0, 1}], Clip[2 x - 21/25, {0, 1}], Piecewise[{{4 x, 0 <= x < 1/4}, {1, 1/4 <= x < 21/50}, {46/25 - 2 x, 21/50 <= x < 23/25}, {(25 x - 23)/2, 23/25 <= x <= 1}}]]`

Answer (score 9):

The gradient of interest here is actually a [Gnuplot](http://gnuplot.sf.net) color scheme. From [here](https://astro.uni-bonn.de/~ithies/gnuplot/colortools/rgbformulae.gp) we find that "AFM hot" corresponds to using components 34, 35, and 36 (with suitable clipping). Thus,

```
afmhot[x_] /; 0 <= x <= 1 :=
RGBColor[Min[2 x, 1], Min[Max[0, 2 x - 1/2], 1], Max[0, 2 x - 1]]
```

or, using `Blend[]`,

```
afmhot[x_] /; 0 <= x <= 1 :=
Blend[{Black, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 1/2, 0],
       RGBColor[1, 1, 1/2], White}, x]
```

Test:

```
LinearGradientImage[afmhot, {300, 30}]
```

[image: gradient]

```
Plot3D[1/10 + (1 - (x - 2)^2) (1 - (y - 2)^2), {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3},
       ColorFunction -> (afmhot[#3] &)]
```

[image: see the colors]

Answer (score 5):

As Vitaliy pointed out, you can always define your own colour scheme.

```
clfun = Blend[{Black, Red, Yellow, White}, #] &; (*color scheme*)
Plot3D[0.1 + (1 - (x - 2)^2) (1 - (y - 2)^2), {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, clfun[z]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Before *Mathematica* had all the colour gradients, I used this blend:

```
RedTempX[x_] := RGBColor[Min[{1, 4x/3}], Max[{0, 2x-1}], Max[{0, 4x-3}]]
```

Don't forget you can use an exponent to modify how the colours appear. Here I used an exponent of 0.5.

```
 Plot3D[0.1 + (1 - (x - 2)^2) (1 - (y - 2)^2), {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3},
        ColorFunction -> (RedTempX[#3^0.5] &), Mesh -> 20]
```

[image: temperature colour gradient]