# How to rescale ColorData in a non-linear fashion?

Tags: color

I want to use `Rescale` on a `ColorData`, like this:

```
ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-100, 10}}]
```

However, I still want the value 0 to get plotted with the white color of the scheme. Any idea how to force Mma to do so?
I tried "specific discrete values" `{{x1, x2, ...}}` but it's not working.

Comment: You want the blue to correspond to -100, the White to 0, and the Red to still correspond to 10?

Comment: This is correct!

Comment: @JasonB - I managed to get the desired `ColorFunction` with `Blend`. I was just hoping for a more easier way with `Rescale` and a `ColorScheme` or so...

Comment: Consider using an interpolating polynomial as the mapping function, mapping $-100,0,10$ to $0,1/2,1$. Adjust derivative values (Hermite interpolation) if need be.

Comment: @J.M. - Could you give an example? I mean, how to incorporate that into the properties of `ColorData`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is a nonlinear function to map to, one that is close to zero for values near `x=-100`, reaches 1/2 at `x=0`, and 1 at `x=10`.  This works,

```
Plot[Exp[x Log[2]/10]/2, {x, -100, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

So applying this to a `ColorFunction`

```
cf = ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Exp[# Log[2]/10]/2] &

BarLegend[{cf, {-100, 10}}]
```

[image]

### Using a 3-point Interpolating function

J.M. suggested using a 3-point interpolation function, which at first I was unable to get to work.  Here is a naive attempt, and remember that the function must stay between 0 and 1.

```
Plot[Interpolation[{{-100, 0}, {0, .5}, {10, 1}}][x], {x, -100, 10}]
```

[image]

Then I read the rest of his comment, about supplying derivatives.  Still thinking about the exponential function above, I assumed the derivative should start at some small value and be monotonically increasing.

```
Plot[Interpolation[{{{-100}, 0, .001}, {{0}, 1/2, 1}, {{10}, 1, 2}}][
  x], {x, -100, 10}]
```

[image]

which would clearly make an awful color map since more than one value would correspond to a single color.

Here are derivative values that seem to work

```
fun = Interpolation[{{{-100}, 0, 0}, {{0}, 1/2, .015}, {{10}, 
     1, .015}}];
{Plot[fun[x], {x, -100, 10}],
 BarLegend[{ColorData["TemperatureMap"][fun[#]] &, {-100, 10}}]}
```

You could use `Manipulate` to get just the right color function as well,

```
Manipulate[
 fun = Interpolation[{{{-100}, 0, d1}, {{0}, 1/2, d2}, {{10}, 1, d3}}];
 {Plot[fun[x], {x, -100, 10}, ImageSize -> 300],
  BarLegend[{ColorData["TemperatureMap"][fun[#]] &, {-100, 10}}]},
 {d1, 0, .02}, {d2, 0, .02}, {d3, 0, .02}]
```

[image]

Gonna take this time to mention [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107573/9490) which allows you to create a completely custom color function interactively.

Comment: Nice one, thanks a lot! Lesson learned: my skills on handling `#` and `&` are to be improved!!

Comment: You could just as easily write that as `cf[x_]: = ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Exp[x Log[2]/10]/2] `, but hang around here long enough and you use pure functions and `Map` for everything

Comment: Also, see [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102132/9490) for some more nonlinear color functions

Comment: Yeah, I already realized, that these commands might save tons of coding text. But I'm still not very familiar with them. Anyway, my time is limited so I'll learn it *peux á peux* :D

Comment: Thanks for following through. :)

Comment: My pleasure since I was not aware that you could supply derivatives so easily to `Interpolation`

Answer (score 5):

It can be done by applying `ColorData["TemperatureMap"]` to a piecewise function that rescales the intervals -100 to 0 and 0 to 10 separately.

```
cf[u_] =
  ColorData["TemperatureMap"] @ 
    Piecewise[
      {{Rescale[u, {-100, 0}, {0., .5}], -100 < u < 0}, 
       {Rescale[u, {0, 10}, {.5, 1.}], 0 <= u <= 10}}];

DensityPlot[x, {x, -100, 10}, {y, 0, 1},
  ColorFunction -> cf,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Since

```
ColorData["TemperatureMap"] @ 
  Piecewise[
    {{Rescale[u, {-100, 0}, {0., .5}], -100 < u < 0}, 
     {Rescale[u, {0, 10}, {.5, 1.}], 0 <= u <= 10}}]
```

returns a color blend, `cf` can be written more directly as

```
cf[u_] =
  Blend[
    "TemperatureMap", 
    Piecewise[{{0.5 + 0.005 u, -100 < u < 0}, {0.5 + 0.05 u, 0 <= u <= 10}}]];
```

Further, as J.M. suggests in his comment, an interpolating function can be used.

```
cf[u_] = 
  (ColorData["TemperatureMap"] @*
     Interpolation[{{-100, 0.}, {0, .5}, {10, 1.}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1])[u];
```

or

```
cf[u_] =
  Blend[
   "TemperatureMap",
   Interpolation[{{-100, 0.}, {0, .5}, {10, 1.}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][u]];
```

Comment: Equivalently, one could have used `Interpolation[]` with the setting `InterpolationOrder -> 1`.