# How to set zero of bicolor ColorData?

Tags: plotting, color, scaling

Let me pose the question through an example:

Normally, to set the `ColorFunction` for, say, a `ListDensityPlot`, I would write

```
myColorFunc = ColorData[{"GreenPinkTones", {-30, 10}}];
ColorFunctionScaling -> False;
```

In this example, though, the white of the `ColorFunction` comes at `-10`, whilst I would like to have shades of `Green` from `-30` to `0`, and shades of `Pink` from `0` to `10`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `cf = Blend[{{-30, Green}, {0, White}, {10, Pink}}, #] &;
BarLegend[{cf, {-30, 10}}]`  see [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html)

Comment: You can also look [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/847480?sortMsg=Votes) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64439/9490) for graphical interfaces to create your own color function

Comment: `cf = ColorData[{"GreenPinkTones", {-30, 30}}][2 # + Abs@#] &`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make your own bi-linear mapping:

```
myColorFunc = (ColorData["GreenPinkTones"][
               Piecewise[{
                          {Rescale[#, {-30, 0 }, {0, 1/2}], # < 0},
                          {Rescale[#, {0  , 10}, {1/2, 1}], # >= 0}}]]) &;

BarLegend[{myColorFunc, {-30, 10}},LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image: shifted color gradient]

Comment: Thank you very much. This gets the job done. Thanks also to @JasonB. for his input. Both the solutions work well.
This is a great community.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to shift the position of a middle color of a gradient uses the ["bias" function of Schlick](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=brDfBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA401) (with suitable rescaling) along with a color gradient. Here is a small demo:

```
bias[h_, x_] := bias[h, x, {0, 1}];
bias[h_, x_, {a_, b_}] := a + (x - a)/(1 + (1/h - 2) (1 - (x - a)/(b - a)))

Manipulate[DensityPlot[x, {x, -30, 10}, {y, 0, 5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
                       ColorFunction -> Function[x, ColorData[{gradient, {-30, 10}},
                                                              bias[h, x, {-30, 10}]]], 
                       ColorFunctionScaling -> False, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None}, 
                       PlotLabel -> Row[{"h=", Round[h, 0.001]}]], 
           Row[{Control[{{gradient, "GreenPinkTones"}, ColorData["Gradients"],
                         ControlType -> PopupMenu}],
                Control[{{h, 0.5}, 0, 1}]}, Spacer[20]]]
```

[image: example of "biased" gradient]

where we see through experimentation that setting `h = 0.25` shifts the white color to `0`. To confirm:

```
Solve[bias[h, 0, {-30, 10}] == bias[1/2, Mean[{-30, 10}], {-30, 10}], h]
   {{h -> 1/4}}
```

Thus, here is the final color function you need:

```
mycf = ColorData[{"GreenPinkTones", {-30, 10}}, bias[1/4, #, {-30, 10}]] &;
BarLegend[{mycf, {-30, 10}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image: bar legend with biased color]