# Interactive ColorFunction using ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color

I try to use `Manipulate` to  specify my interactive own colors and scaling for the `ColorFunction` in `ListContourPlot`. In the forum I found this very useful code

```
 Manipulate[{a, x, y, z, b} = 
  Rescale[{aa, xx, yy, zz, bb}, MinMax@{aa, xx, yy, zz, bb}];
 colors = 
  Transpose[{{a, x, y, z, b}, {Blue, Lighter@LightBlue, White, Yellow,
      Red}}];
 DensityPlot[
  Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {y, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[colors, #] &), PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 100], {{aa, 0, "Blue"}, 0, 
  1, .01}, {{xx, 0.25, "Lighter@LightBlue"}, 0, 
  1, .01}, {{yy, .5, "White"}, 0, 1, .01}, {{zz, .75, "Yellow"}, 0, 
  1, .01}, {{bb, 1, "Red"}, 0, 1, .01}]
Dynamic[colors]
```

How can I adapt it for my *ColorFunction* and my *data* instead of *Sin[x] Cos[y]*

```
myTemperatureMap[f_] := 
  Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {-0.25, Lighter@LightBlue}, {-0.25, White}, {0, 
     White}, {0.3, Yellow}, {0.6, Red}}, f];


data = Import[file, "Table", HeaderLines -> 2]; 
dataT = Transpose[data];
dataT = {dataT[[1]]*10, dataT[[2]]*10, dataT[[3]]}; 
dataT[[3]] = Rescale[dataT[[3]], MinMax[dataT[[3]]], {-1., 1.}];

ListContourPlot[data,
  PlotRange -> {{-0.05, 0.05}, {-0.05, 0.05}, {-1., 1.}},
  ColorFunction -> myTemperatureMap, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> None, Contours -> 200,
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{myTemperatureMap[#] &, {-1, 1}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
    LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}], Bold, 
        Black, 12] &)]];
```

I tried this but doesn't work the color doesn't change...

```
Manipulate[{a, x, y, z, b} = Rescale[{aa, xx, yy, zz, bb}, MinMax@{aa, xx, yy, zz, bb}];
colors = Transpose[{{a, x, y, z, b}, {Blue, Lighter@LightBlue, White, 
    Yellow, Red}}];
 ListContourPlot[data,
  ColorFunction -> myTemperatureMap, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> None, Contours -> 200,
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{myTemperatureMap[#] &, {-1, 1}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
    LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}], Bold, 
        Black, 12] &)]], {{aa, 0, "Blue"}, -1, 1, .01}, {{xx, 0.25, "Lighter@LightBlue"}, -1, 1, .01}, {{yy, .5, "White"}, -1, 1, .01}, {{zz, .75, "Yellow"}, -1, 1, .01}, {{bb, 1, "Red"}, -1, 1, .01}]
Dynamic[colors]
```

Comment: do you get the desired result if you change the lower limit of controls to `-1`,, e.g. `{{bb, 1, "Red"}, -1, 1, .01}` and put your `ListContourPlot` in place of `DensityPlot` in `Manipulate[...]` ?

Comment: I tried this (see edited code) but the colors doesn't change...

Comment: And I don't see my plot only the panel...

Comment: similar, if not duplicate, post here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64439/9490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Table[{#, #2, .8 Sin[#] Cos[#2]} & @@ RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 2], {1000}];

Manipulate[{a, x, y, w, z, b} = 
  Rescale[{aa, xx, yy, ww, zz, bb}, MinMax@{aa, xx, yy, ww, zz, bb}];
 colors = Transpose[{{a, x, y, w, z, b}, {Blue, Lighter@LightBlue, White, 
     White, Yellow, Red}}];
 ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[colors, #] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ContourStyle -> None, 
  Contours -> 200, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Blend[colors, #] &, {-1, 1}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
    LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}], Bold, Black, 12] &)]], 
  {{aa, -1, "Blue"}, -1,  1, .01}, 
  {{xx, -0.25, "Lighter@LightBlue"}, -1, 1, .01}, 
  {{yy, -.25, "White"}, -1, 1, .01}, 
  {{ww, 0., "White"}, -1, 1, .01}, 
 {{zz, .3, "Yellow"}, -1, 1, .01}, {{bb, .6, "Red"}, -1, 1, .01}]
```

[image]

Comment: In my case data is a Table of three column. Should I write data = Table[{#,#2,#3}&@@file] because when I replace your data by my data it doesn’t work...

Comment: If your data is a list of triples, (`data = { {x1,y1, z1},, {x2, y2, z2}, ...,{xn,yn,zn}}`) , then it should work. Check  `Dimensions[data]` to make sure it is `{somenumber, 3}`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will check it.

Comment: I checked, my Dimension is 3. When I run it, it never stop and I get  the following message  > the Kernel is not responding to Dynamic Evaluation... But otherwise, when I use your function, it works well...