# Create a color function from dynamic panel

Tags: functions, dynamic, color

I would like to generate a color function [from the dynamic panel code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/how-can-i-create-an-interactive-colorfunction-using-manipulate) and use it as I want...instead of using Copy to Clip Board and then past in `myTM`....
Any idea ? I dont want to use Copy and past in `myTM`, I would like to use directly the results from the dynamic panel without any click

Here my code

```
(*Dynamic panel*)
With[{cmax = 12},(*maximum number of colors*)
 DynamicModule[{k = 5, cols = {White, LightBlue, Yellow, Orange, Red},
    vals = {0, 0.35, 0.75, 0.95, 1}}, 
  Panel[Column[{Column[{Row[{Dynamic[
          Style["colors: " <> IntegerString[k], Bold]], Spacer[20], 
         Slider[Dynamic[k, (k = #; cols = PadRight[cols, k, Gray];

             vals = Rescale[
               ArrayPad[vals, {0, k - Length[vals]}, 
                "Extrapolated"]]) &], {2, cmax, 1}]}], 
       Dynamic[Multicolumn[
         Array[Column[{ColorSlider[Dynamic[cols[[#]]]], 
             Row[{Dynamic[Style[vals[[#]], Small, Bold]], Spacer[20], 
               Slider[Dynamic[vals[[#]]], {0, 1}, 
                ImageSize -> Small]}]}] &, k], 5, 
         Appearance -> "Horizontal"], TrackedSymbols :> {k}]}], 
     Dynamic[With[{cl = Transpose[{vals, cols}]}, 
       Column[{Panel[
          LinearGradientImage[
           Blend[cl, Rescale[#, {0, 1}, MinMax[vals]]] &, {600, 60}]],
          Button["Copy to clipboard", 
          CopyToClipboard[Defer[Blend[cl, f]]], ImageSize -> Medium, 
          Method -> "Queued"]}]]]}]]]]

(*data*)
data = Table[{#, #2, Sin[#] Cos[#2]} & @@ 
    RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 2], {1000}];


(*MyColor function with Gamma correction*)
Table[MapAt[#^(1/\[Gamma]) &, Brown, ;; 3], {\[Gamma], {0.4, 1, 2.2}}];
    gamma[\[Gamma]_][c_?ColorQ] := 
  MapAt[#1^(1/\[Gamma]) &, ColorConvert[c, "RGB"], ;; 3];
myTM[\[Gamma]_] := 
  gamma[\[Gamma]]@
    Blend[{{0, GrayLevel[1]}, {0.35`, RGBColor[
       0.5700000000000001, 0.76, 1.]}, {0.75`, RGBColor[
       1, 1, 0]}, {0.95`, RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]}, {1, RGBColor[
       1, 0, 0]}}, #] &(*past my color function here*);

(*My graphics*)

graph3 = ListDensityPlot[data,
  ColorFunction -> myTM[0.1],
  PlotRange -> All,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Linear", "Linear"},
  ImageSize -> UpTo[850]
  ]
```

Comment: Please describe how do you imagine the flow. Have you tried to put your definition of `myTM` to the button instead of CopyToClipboard?

Comment: I edited and put the link I used to generate the dynamic color panel. My definition of my TM is a combination of a gamma function and the Blend colors function I get from the dynamic panel...How can I replace my button with myTM ?