# density plot : same colors for same values

Tags: plotting, color

```
data = {{0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00913538}, {0.00001, 0.10001, 
  14.0666}, {0.00001, 0.20001, 22.0695}, {0.00001, 0.30001, 
  27.8521}, {0.00001, 0.40001, 32.3443}, {0.00001, 0.50001, 
  35.9819}, {0.00001, 0.60001, 39.0109}, {0.00001, 0.70001, 
  41.5849}, {0.00001, 0.80001, 43.8067}, {0.00001, 0.90001, 
  45.7485}, {0.10001, 0.00001, 14.0666}, {0.10001, 0.10001, 
  26.1478}, {0.10001, 0.20001, 33.0256}, {0.10001, 0.30001, 
  37.9952}, {0.10001, 0.40001, 41.8559}, {0.10001, 0.50001, 
  44.9821}, {0.10001, 0.60001, 47.5852}, {0.10001, 0.70001, 
  49.7973}, {0.10001, 0.80001, 51.7068}, {0.10001, 0.90001, 
  53.3756}, {0.20001, 0.00001, 22.0695}, {0.20001, 0.10001, 
  33.0256}, {0.20001, 0.20001, 39.2628}, {0.20001, 0.30001, 
  43.7696}, {0.20001, 0.40001, 47.2707}, {0.20001, 0.50001, 
  50.1058}, {0.20001, 0.60001, 52.4665}, {0.20001, 0.70001, 
  54.4726}, {0.20001, 0.80001, 56.2042}, {0.20001, 0.90001, 
  57.7176}, {0.30001, 0.00001, 27.8521}, {0.30001, 0.10001, 
  37.9952}, {0.30001, 0.20001, 43.7696}, {0.30001, 0.30001, 
  47.942}, {0.30001, 0.40001, 51.1833}, {0.30001, 0.50001, 
  53.8081}, {0.30001, 0.60001, 55.9936}, {0.30001, 0.70001, 
  57.8508}, {0.30001, 0.80001, 59.454}, {0.30001, 0.90001, 
  60.8551}, {0.40001, 0.00001, 32.3443}, {0.40001, 0.10001, 
  41.8559}, {0.40001, 0.20001, 47.2707}, {0.40001, 0.30001, 
  51.1833}, {0.40001, 0.40001, 54.2229}, {0.40001, 0.50001, 
  56.6842}, {0.40001, 0.60001, 58.7336}, {0.40001, 0.70001, 
  60.4752}, {0.40001, 0.80001, 61.9785}, {0.40001, 0.90001, 
  63.2924}, {0.50001, 0.00001, 35.9819}, {0.50001, 0.10001, 
  44.9821}, {0.50001, 0.20001, 50.1058}, {0.50001, 0.30001, 
  53.8081}, {0.50001, 0.40001, 56.6842}, {0.50001, 0.50001, 
  59.0131}, {0.50001, 0.60001, 60.9524}, {0.50001, 0.70001, 
  62.6004}, {0.50001, 0.80001, 64.0228}, {0.50001, 0.90001, 
  65.2661}, {0.60001, 0.00001, 39.0109}, {0.60001, 0.10001, 
  47.5852}, {0.60001, 0.20001, 52.4665}, {0.60001, 0.30001, 
  55.9936}, {0.60001, 0.40001, 58.7336}, {0.60001, 0.50001, 
  60.9524}, {0.60001, 0.60001, 62.7999}, {0.60001, 0.70001, 
  64.3699}, {0.60001, 0.80001, 65.7251}, {0.60001, 0.90001, 
  66.9095}, {0.70001, 0.00001, 41.5849}, {0.70001, 0.10001, 
  49.7973}, {0.70001, 0.20001, 54.4726}, {0.70001, 0.30001, 
  57.8508}, {0.70001, 0.40001, 60.4752}, {0.70001, 0.50001, 
  62.6004}, {0.70001, 0.60001, 64.3699}, {0.70001, 0.70001, 
  65.8736}, {0.70001, 0.80001, 67.1716}, {0.70001, 0.90001, 
  68.306}, {0.80001, 0.00001, 43.8067}, {0.80001, 0.10001, 
  51.7068}, {0.80001, 0.20001, 56.2042}, {0.80001, 0.30001, 
  59.454}, {0.80001, 0.40001, 61.9785}, {0.80001, 0.50001, 
  64.0228}, {0.80001, 0.60001, 65.7251}, {0.80001, 0.70001, 
  67.1716}, {0.80001, 0.80001, 68.4202}, {0.80001, 0.90001, 
  69.5115}, {0.90001, 0.00001, 45.7485}, {0.90001, 0.10001, 
  53.3756}, {0.90001, 0.20001, 57.7176}, {0.90001, 0.30001, 
  60.8551}, {0.90001, 0.40001, 63.2924}, {0.90001, 0.50001, 
  65.2661}, {0.90001, 0.60001, 66.9095}, {0.90001, 0.70001, 
  68.306}, {0.90001, 0.80001, 69.5115}, {0.90001, 0.90001, 70.565}}
```

I plot the data:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotLegends -> {Placed[Automatic, Right]}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"]]
```

[image]

Now I have other data:

```
data2={{0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00913538}, {0.00001, 0.10001, 
  14.0666}, {0.00001, 0.20001, 22.0695}, {0.00001, 0.30001, 
  27.8521}, {0.00001, 0.40001, 32.3443}, {0.10001, 0.00001, 
  14.0666}, {0.10001, 0.10001, 26.1478}, {0.10001, 0.20001, 
  33.0256}, {0.10001, 0.30001, 37.9952}, {0.10001, 0.40001, 
  41.8559}, {0.20001, 0.00001, 22.0695}, {0.20001, 0.10001, 
  33.0256}, {0.20001, 0.20001, 39.2628}, {0.20001, 0.30001, 
  43.7696}, {0.20001, 0.40001, 47.2707}, {0.30001, 0.00001, 
  27.8521}, {0.30001, 0.10001, 37.9952}, {0.30001, 0.20001, 
  43.7696}, {0.30001, 0.30001, 47.942}, {0.30001, 0.40001, 
  51.1833}, {0.40001, 0.00001, 32.3443}, {0.40001, 0.10001, 
  41.8559}, {0.40001, 0.20001, 47.2707}, {0.40001, 0.30001, 
  51.1833}, {0.40001, 0.40001, 54.2229}}
```

Again, I can plot it:
[image]

Now my question is: *How can I make sure that the color assigned to each value in the first plot is assigned to the same values in the second plot ?*

Comment: closely related: [Set the same color scale across multiple ListContourPlots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64330/125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MinMax[]` to get the extent of the $z$-values in `data`:

```
dzr = MinMax[data[[All, 3]]];
```

From there, feed this range into `ColorData[]`, and set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
Column[{ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", dzr}], 
                        ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> Small, 
                        PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right]], 
        ListDensityPlot[data2, ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", dzr}],
                        ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> Small, 
                        PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right]]}]
```

[image: two plots]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is perfect ! :)